# About array pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, string-literals

How can I get 'l' from this array pointer?

```
char *p[3][2] = {"abc", "defg", "hi", "jklmno", "pqrstuvw", "xyz"};
```

like

```
printf("%c\n",*((*p)) + 2);
```

Comment: Show what you are going to output.

Comment: Use subscripts, not indirections with `*`.  There's a reason subscripts were invented; they're easier to read and get right.  You need `p[1][1][2]` to get `l` from `p`.  If you're perverse enough to want to do that with indirections, use `p[i] === *(p + i)` repeatedly.  The nesting will be messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use fully brace-enclosed declarations to make your array initializer clearer

```
char *p[3][2] = {{"abc", "defg"}, {"hi", "jklmno"}, {"pqrstuvw", "xyz"}};
```

now you can see that `p[1]` is the array `{"hi", "jklmno"}`.
then you want to get the second string, which is `p[1][1]` and then the 3rd character: `p[1][1][2]`.

Here is a running example: https://ideone.com/Jd9GWI

Comment: The original is correct but not particularly good style. The standard says so (mainly for reasons of backwards compatibility, but that doesn't make it much less correct). It isn't marked deprecated by the "Future directions" section of the standard. Using "Let's correct your line" is over-statement; using "Let's {clarify|revise} your line" would not be over-statement. Using "Let's use fully brace-enclosed declarations to make your array initializer clearer" would be good, if a little clumsy on 'brace-enclosed'; I'd probably use "fully bracketed", but 'brace-enclosed' is what the standard says.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly you are going to output the letter 'l' from the string literal `"jklmno"` using pointers.

This literal is in the row with the index `1` and in the column also with the index `1`.

So to get access to the literal using the subscript operator you could write the expression `p[1][1]` that yields the pointer to the first character of the string literal. Now to get the character 'l' of the string literal you could write the expression `p[1][1][2]`.

```
printf( "%c\n", p[1][1][2] );
```

Now let's do the same using pointers without the subscript operator.

An array designator used in expression with rare exceptions is converted to pointer to its first element.

Thus used in expressions the array designator `p` is converted to a pointer of the type `char * ( * )[2]` that points to the first row of the array.

To get a pointer to the second row of the array you should write `p + 1`.

To get the row itself you have to dereference the pointer

```
*( p + 1 )
```

This expression has the type `char *[2]`.

But again as this expression is a designator of a one-dimensional array then used in expressions it is converted to pointer to its first element and has the type `char **`.

To access a pointer to the second element of the row you can use the pointer arithmetic

```
*( p + 1 ) + 1
```

To get the pointed element (string literal) you have to dereference the pointer

```
*( *( p + 1 ) + 1 )
```

this expression has the type char * and points to the first character of the string literal `"jklmno"`.

To get a pointer to the third character of the string literal you have to use this expression

```
*( *( p + 1 ) + 1 ) + 2
```

Now you need to dereference the pointer to output the pointed letter `'l'`.

```
*( *( *( p + 1 ) + 1 ) + 2 )
```

So the function call will look like

```
printf( "%c\n", *( *( *( p + 1 ) + 1 ) + 2 ) );
```

Compare it with the previously shown function call

```
printf( "%c\n", p[1][1][2] );
```

Take into account that if you have an array like

```
T a[N];
```

where `T` is some type then using the subscript operator to access the `i-th` element of the array you can write the expression `a[i]`. Under the hood this expression is evaluated using the pointer arithmetic like `*( a + i )`. Due to the commutative nature of the addition operator this expression can be written also like `*( i + a )`.. So using the subscript operator you may write the expression `i[a]` that is equivalent to the expression `a[i]`.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Thus the expression

```
*( *( *( p + 1 ) + 1 ) + 2 )
```

may be rewritten like

```
*( 2 + *( 1 + *( 1 + p ) ) )
```

and correspondingly like

```
2[1[1[p]]]
```

and the call of the function `printf`

```
printf( "%c\n", p[1][1][2] );
```

also may be rewritten like (though you should not do this making the code obfuscated)

```
printf( "%c\n", 2[1[1[p]]] );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char *p[3][2] = 
    {
        { "abc", "defg" }, 
        { "hi", "jklmno" },
        { "pqrstuvw", "xyz" }
    };
    
    printf( "%c\n", 2[1[1[p]]] );
}
```

Its output is

```
l
```